# Generate HTML table with complex nested JSON

Tags: php, html, json

I want PHP to generate an HTML table from a nested JSON object. I want the output to resemble the format shown in the image. The main challenges lie in handling the rowspan and colspan. While I can calculate the rowspan, I am encountering difficulties with the colspan. I need a recursive PHP function. The current one creates a table in each `<td>`, but I want `<tr>` to be like in the image:

[image]

The JSON can have an unlimited number of levels.

```php
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

function generateTable($data) {
    $html = '<table border="1">';
    foreach ($data as $item) {
 if(is_array($item['node']['value']))
      {
        $rowspan = count($item['node']['value']);
      }
        $html .= '<tr rowspan='.$rowspan.'>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>' . $item['node']['key'] . '</th>';
        $html .= '<td>';
        if (isset($item['node']['value']) && is_array($item['node']['value'])) {
            $html .= generateTable($item['node']['value']);
        } else {
            $html .= $item['node']['value'];
        }
        $html .= '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
    $html .= '</table>';
    return $html;
}

echo generateTable($data);
```

```json
[
    {
       "node":{
          "key":"header",
          "value":[
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"msg_id",
                   "value":"236001"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":12,
                "desc":"Message ID, this field should be unique id for each Api call. This will be generated from client side. \n\n If the same message ID is used the system will decline the API call with Error Description “Duplicate Message ID” ",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"msg_type",
                   "value":"TRANSACTION"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":12,
                "desc":"Message Type – This can have either “TRANSACTION” or “ENQUIRY” \n\n As for this API the value expected is “TRANSACTION” ",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"msg_function",
                   "value":"REQ_ACCOUNT_CREATE"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":50,
                "desc":"Message functions: Should be  “REQ_ACCOUNT_CREATE” ",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"src_application",
                   "value":"IVR"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":10,
                "desc":"Source Application: This is a free Text and the client can populate the source system from where the API is Initiated \n\n Example: IVR, IB, MB \n\n No Validations of these are kept at Network Systems",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"target_application",
                   "value":"WAY4"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":10,
                "desc":"The target_application can hold any value from FI side, this can be used by FI to check the target system of the API call",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"timestamp",
                   "value":"2020-07-20T10:49:02.366+04:00"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":30,
                "desc":"Timestamp of the request - Format  YYYY-MM-DDtHH:MM:SS.SSS+04:00",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"bank_id",
                   "value":"NIC"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":4,
                "desc":"Bank Id is Unique Id 4 digit code for each client and the same will be provided once the client setup is completed in our core system. \n\n For sandbox testing – Please use “NIC” ",
                "req":"required"
             }
          ]
       },
       "type":"object",
       "minLength":null,
       "maxLength":null,
       "desc":"",
       "req":"false"
    },
    {
       "node":{
          "key":"body",
          "value":[
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"customer_id",
                   "value":"100000027"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":20,
                "desc":"Customer ID: Customer Identification number \n\n This should be a unique number",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"card_type",
                   "value":"CREDIT"
                },
                "type":"string",
                "minLength":1,
                "maxLength":7,
                "desc":"Informative value to the request, does not have any functional impact, the value can be PREPAID/CREDIT/DEBIT",
                "req":"required"
             },
             {
                "node":{
                   "key":"account",
                   "value":[
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"customer_id",
                            "value":"100000027"
                         },
                         "type":"string",
                         "minLength":1,
                         "maxLength":20,
                         "desc":"Customer ID: Customer Identification number \n\n This should be a unique number",
                         "req":"required"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"account_number",
                            "value":"0009821110000000008"
                         },
                         "type":"string",
                         "minLength":1,
                         "maxLength":64,
                         "desc":"Account number, if not provided CMS will generate it",
                         "req":"false"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"parent_account_number",
                            "value":"0009821110000000008"
                         },
                         "type":"string",
                         "minLength":1,
                         "maxLength":64,
                         "desc":"Parent account number - Applicable only for Corporate products",
                         "req":"false"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"branch_code",
                            "value":"982"
                         },
                         "type":"string",
                         "minLength":1,
                         "maxLength":10,
                         "desc":"Branch Code, if no branches are used, the code must be same as bank_code",
                         "req":"required"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"product_code",
                            "value":"982_AED_002_A"
                         },
                         "type":"string",
                         "minLength":1,
                         "maxLength":32,
                         "desc":"Product code, this code is generated by CMS after creating the product, this code is FI spesific code 982_AED_002_A is just used as an example in Sandbox",
                         "req":"required"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"billing_day",
                            "value":""
                         },
                         "type":"string",
                         "minLength":1,
                         "maxLength":10,
                         "desc":"Billing date, applicable only for credit card products",
                         "req":"false"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"currency",
                            "value":"AED"
                         },
                         "type":"string",
                         "minLength":1,
                         "maxLength":3,
                         "desc":"Informative value to the request, does not have any functional impact, the currency will be taken from the product",
                         "req":"required"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"limit",
                            "value":[
                               {
                                  "node":{
                                     "key":"type",
                                     "value":"FIN_LIMIT"
                                  },
                                  "type":"string",
                                  "minLength":1,
                                  "maxLength":32,
                                  "desc":"Credit limit type - applicable only for credit card products",
                                  "req":"false"
                               },
                               {
                                  "node":{
                                     "key":"currency",
                                     "value":"SAR"
                                  },
                                  "type":"string",
                                  "minLength":1,
                                  "maxLength":3,
                                  "desc":"Credit limit currency - applicable only for credit card products",
                                  "req":"false"
                               },
                               {
                                  "node":{
                                     "key":"value",
                                     "value":"55000"
                                  },
                                  "type":"string",
                                  "minLength":1,
                                  "maxLength":20,
                                  "desc":"Credit limit value - applicable only for credit card products",
                                  "req":"false"
                               }
                            ]
                         },
                         "type":"object",
                         "minLength":null,
                         "maxLength":null,
                         "desc":"",
                         "req":"false"
                      },
                      {
                         "node":{
                            "key":"custom_fields",
                            "value":[
                               {
                                  "node":{
                                     "key":"key",
                                     "value":"contract_idt_scheme"
                                  },
                                  "type":"string",
                                  "minLength":1,
                                  "maxLength":20,
                                  "desc":"Custom Tag. Example: contract_idt_scheme",
                                  "req":"false"
                               },
                               {
                                  "node":{
                                     "key":"value",
                                     "value":"CONTRACT_NUMBER"
                                  },
                                  "type":"string",
                                  "minLength":1,
                                  "maxLength":128,
                                  "desc":"Tag value. Example: CONTRACT_NUMBER",
                                  "req":"false"
                               }
                            ]
                         },
                         "type":"array",
                         "minLength":null,
                         "maxLength":null,
                         "desc":"",
                         "req":"false"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                "type":"object",
                "minLength":null,
                "maxLength":null,
                "desc":"",
                "req":"required"
             }
          ]
       },
       "type":"object",
       "minLength":null,
       "maxLength":null,
       "desc":"",
       "req":"false"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: (1) What did you attempt ? Show your code please  (2) It is not quite clear what do you actually want - the two images you posted seems similar / or actually are the same ?

Comment: You wrote ", i can calculate rowspan but having problem in rowspan, ", which appears to be contradictory. Were one of the "rowspan" meant to be "colspan" instead?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a _minimal_ [mcve] to me.  It looks like a requirements dump.

Comment: It is unclear what the relation is between the picture in your question and the JSON in your question.

Comment: i want to generate html table as shown in that image.